# Google Finance: How big is a normal delay for historical stock data or is something broken?

Tags: pandas, finance, google-finance, pandas-datareader

I tried to download historical data from Google with this code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import datetime

web_df = wb.DataReader("ETR:DAI", 'google',
                       datetime.date(2017,9,1),
                       datetime.date(2017,9,7))
print(web_df)
```

and got this:

```
             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
Date                                           
2017-09-01  61.38  62.16  61.22  61.80  3042884
2017-09-04  61.40  62.01  61.31  61.84  1802854
2017-09-05  62.01  62.92  61.77  62.42  3113816
```

My question: Is this a normal delay or is something broken?

Also I would want to know: Have you noticed that Google has removed the historical data pages at Google Finance? Is this a hint that the will remove or allready have removed the download option for historical stock data, too?

Comment: Do you mean the missing dates? It's the weekend.

Comment: There are values for 2017-09-06 and 2017-09-07 missing! Is this a normal delay or is something broken or does Google no longer provide historical stock data??? I'm a bit worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google finance using pandas has stopped working since last night, I am trying to figure out.I have also noticed that the links to the historical data on their website is removed.

Comment: If there's a discussion on this topic please provide a link. Thank you very much. :(

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which stocks and which market.
Example with Indonesia market, it still able to get latest data. Of course, it may be soon to follow the fate of others market that stop updating on 5 September 2017. A very sad things

```
web_df = wb.DataReader("IDX:AALI", 'google',
                       datetime.date(2017,9,1),
                       datetime.date(2017,9,7))

             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
Date
2017-09-04  14750.0  14975.0  14675.0  14700.0    475700
2017-09-05  14700.0  14900.0  14650.0  14850.0    307300
2017-09-06  14850.0  14850.0  14700.0  14725.0    219900

2017-09-07  14775.0  14825.0  14725.0  14725.0    153300
```

Comment: DataReader can interact with Quandl, maybe this will help (?). I've a look at this source at the moment...

Comment: FYI, your ticker data is coming back again. Quandl is paid service unless it is US. For those who reserach stocks for non US, we have left no choices between Yahoo or Google. Even we willing to paid, the cost will be a few thousand USD for Bloomberg or Reuters. This is something those US citizen will not understand. They have plenty of cheap data source if not a free one.

Comment: You are right, ticker data is back again with a gap for 2017-09-06 and 2017-09-07. For me Quandl is not an acceptable data source because it does not provide the data completely for my area of interest :( . I'm from Europe.